# android: how pass int value to another's activity from method?

Tags: android

I want to pass the value of my method which I created outside `onCreate()` method.
But I won't use `intent()` because with use intent I had to go another activity with using intent structure ,but I want just pass my value. Is there any way that I can pass the value of my variable or method to another activity without going to that activity?
Thanks for your help.

EDIt : how using in below cod? :

```
public class Main_menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
protected static final Context Main_menu = null;
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

} // for oncreate()

public static void showDialog(final Context context, int id) {
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.Base_Theme_AppCompat_Light);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

// Favorites 
TextView tv_addfavorites=(TextView)     dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_addfavorites);
tv_addfavorites.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

id=id+100;
// <<< i want to pass my value (id) to another activity from here>>>
}
});
}
}
```

Comment: Simply put it in `sharedPreference` and access it with key from any activity.

Comment: If I am correct then you want to pass data from one activity to another without actually visiting that activity. For this, passing data between activities using Interface will be best suited. Google it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put it in `sharedPreference` and access it with key from any activity. Here it is how to do.

```
// create a sharedPreferences
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

// storing using key key/value pair
editor.putInt("score", 200); // here score is a key, value is 200

// commiting changes
editor.commit();
```

To read from the `Sharedprefernce`, just do like

```
pref.getInt("score", 0); // mention your key in 1st paramater
```

this will give you value `200`.

**EDIT :**

To access the value in other activity, first you need to create a sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Then, access it like

```
int score = pref.getInt("score", 0); // mention your key in 1st paramater
```

Don't forget to check it if it is set or taken by default value which is the second parameter.

```
if (score == 0) {
  //Default value
} else {
  //The value is set
}
```

Comment: i do it but "pref" pref cannot be resolved in other activities

Comment: Updated my answer. Check it now.

Comment: thank you can u help me to using this method in my cod?